# Problema con JSON en MVC5

Tags: c#, json, mvc, asp

al momento de escribir JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet me sale marcado que esta mal escrito o no existe, en el controlador.

```
    public JsonResult Clases(string valuemarca)
    {
        return Json(obj2.ObtenerVehiculoClaseAsync("", ServicioMVCDatoAuto.TipoVehiculo.Auto, valuemarca), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: has agregado este namespace? `using System.Web.Mvc;`

Comment: dice que Mvc no existe en el espacio de nombres

Comment: Probablemente te falte referenciar esa dll que señaló @derloopkat

Comment: disculpa soy un poco nuevo, ya descargue esa dll, en que carpeta la meto?

Comment: @JonathanGomez, si creaste el proyecto con la plantilla para MVC ahí la dll debería estar referenciada y no tendrías que hacerlo manualmente. Te recomiendo que busques un buen tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

Ya se que pasó, en los `using` tenia uno que era:

```
using microsoft.aspcore.mvc;
```

Lo quité y le puse

```
using system.web.mvc:
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). No olvides [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Saludos.